# Spring security works with GET but not with other methods

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following security adapter for my Spring REST service to use HTTP basic http auth.
Right now, when I try to send a request to any GET HTTP endpoint, the request is successfully authorized and processed. But all other HTTP methods are returning 401. Any idea?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password")).roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an AuthenticationException which is a runtime exception. Read about it here [Spring Security Authentication](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/#_authentication).
The default configuration of WebSecurity, as said here [HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#jc-httpsecurity) is:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

Try to add `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to your code.